# Where are the java files of NodeConnectorRef?

Tags: java, maven, mininet, opendaylight

I'm working with the bundle of l2switch-release-beryllium-sr3 and I would like to know the methods of some classes like NodeConnectorRef or Node but I don't find these classes. Someone could tell me where to find them?

```
import org.opendaylight.yang.gen.v1.urn.opendaylight.inventory.rev130819.NodeConnectorRef;
import org.opendaylight.yang.gen.v1.urn.opendaylight.inventory.rev130819.nodes.Node;
```

This is the GitHub of l2switch-beryllium: https://github.com/opendaylight/l2swi...

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a generated class. The way to generate it is to include the necessary dependencies in your pom file, such as

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.opendaylight.controller.model</groupId>
  <artifactId>model-inventory</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

The Advanced Search by Classname available [here](https://nexus.opendaylight.org/#nexus-search;classname~org.opendaylight.yang.gen.v1.urn.opendaylight.inventory.rev130819.nodes.Node).

Answer (score 0):

The presence of ".gen" in the package clearly implies that this is a generated class.  You won't find it in the source code.  You'd have to build the application to get the class generated.

Comment: You can also find it in the JAR on Nexus, including sources, and your IDE will propose auto-completion to let you see methods of such YANG binding generated code.